How to correctly place the space at 0101 position
Im using cobol 85 to create a program which inputs number of 10 digits, and if user types "END" the program ends. But i cant seem to clear the screen using DISPLAY AT "position". Is there any suggestions? Thank you. Here is the source code:
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. INPUT-ASSIGMENT.
      ******************************************************************
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
      ******************************************************************
           01  A.
               03  A1 OCCURS 10 TIMES PIC X(3). 
           01  I                  PIC 9(3).
           01  J                  PIC 9(3).
           01  KETA               PIC 9(4).
           01  DT-IN              PIC X(3).
      ******************************************************************
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           PERFORM MAIN-SYORI.
           STOP RUN.
      ******************************************************************
       MAIN-SYORI SECTION.
           PERFORM INITIALIZE-RTN.
           PERFORM TAMEKOMI-SYORI.
           PERFORM TORIDASHI-SYORI.
      ******************************************************************
       INITIALIZE-RTN SECTION.
           DISPLAY SPACE. 
           MOVE 1 TO I.    
           MOVE 1 TO J.
      ******************************************************************
       TAMEKOMI-SYORI SECTION.
           PERFORM UNTIL I > 10 OR DT-IN = "END"
               DISPLAY "3文字を入力してください:" 
               ACCEPT DT-IN
               IF DT-IN NOT = "END"
                   MOVE DT-IN TO A1(I)
                   ADD 1 TO I
               END-IF
           END-PERFORM.
      ******************************************************************
       TORIDASHI-SYORI SECTION.
           DISPLAY SPACE.   
           PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J > I - 1 
               DISPLAY A1(J)
           END-PERFORM.     
           DISPLAY "プログラムは終了しました.".
      ******************************************************************
       END PROGRAM INPUT-ASSIGMENT.


how is "cobol85" related to "cobol.net"?

DISPLAY SPACE AT 0101 WITH ERASE EOS, depending on your use case you may want to WITH ERASE EOL instead.
